# Why is String.HtmlEncode not recognized?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I got following error message

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `System.String
>   HtmlEncode(System.String)` method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Using this LINQ-Statement

```
using (TranEntities model = new TranEntities())
{
      studentNames = (from source in model.Students
                      where source.Name.Contains(pre)
                      select  System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(source.Name.Replace(pre, "<span style='color : red'>" + pre + "</span>"))).ToList();
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's pretty clear that the question involves an explanation of and solution for the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a step from LINQ-to-Entities to LINQ-to-Objects, using [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method, like this:

```
using (TranEntities model = new TranEntities())
{
  var studentNamesE = (from source in model.Students
                  where source.Name.Contains(pre)
                  select source).AsEnumerable();

  studentNames = (from source in studentNamesE
                  select System.Web.HttpUtility
                             .HtmlEncode(source.Name.Replace(pre, 
                                         "<span style='color : red'>" + pre + "</span>")))
                 .ToList();
}
```